# Ground on or Grinded on?

Tags: word-usage, past-tense

Could you please tell me which should be the preferred choice in US English for the past tense form of "grind"?

> It was freezing cold, yet the shooting ground on for days, making most of the actors on set tired.

Is this correct usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The shooting ground on for days.

The "weak" or regular past tense "grinded" is rare, and according to ngrams shows no signs of becoming more popular. The "strong" past tense and past participle is much more common, and should be the preferred form in all cases.

---

This particular sentence is an example of a "garden path sentence". As you read it your initial parsing of the sentence is likely to be wrong, and you have to back up to understand it. It is so-called because a garden path doesn't go anywhere.

"The shooting ground" is initially parsed as a noun phrase, with the noun "ground" and "shooting" is an adjective

"The shooting ground on"  Ok so "on" is a preposition, we expect another noun to follow

"The shooting ground on for" Hmm, that doesn't make sense, I expected a noun, and for is another preposition. Does "on for" mean something, I'm confused.

"The shooting ground on for days"  .... Back up, "shooting" is the noun, and "ground" is a verb. That makes sense. It is only after I go back and reparse the sentence that I can understand its meaning.